# Angular strap tooltip auto placement

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

I'm working with an angular strap dropdown and i want it to stay on screen when it is shown. problem described in the picture.

http://i.imgur.com/cznMsAw.gifv

The [dropdown](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/dropdowns#dropdowns) takes in an placement attribute which can be set to auto to help it stay on screen but it isn't good enough because it only calculates from the parent element not the screen width and height.

This can been seen in the code in the tooltip module

https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/dist/angular-strap.js#L1067

Line 4416 to 4454

does anyone have a solution to this problem.

Comment: Did you try placement="auto" ?

Comment: Like i said in the post i have added the placement attibute and set it to auto. that does not work. im working on a pull request to angular-strap and i will try to fix this problem in the library..

Comment: Ok. please post your answer here after you fixed the issue :)

Comment: here is the issue and pull request. 
https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/1476#issuecomment-72002511